# how to deploy a web application to Google app engine with travis-ci? and what about login?

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment, travis-ci

I´m able to deploy my web application to google app engine via command appengine:update using maven 3.1. But how do I run the same command on travis-ci? I´m afraid of authentication, since the only one I provide in my appengine-web.xml is the application ID. I think it´s not enough.

Comment: possible duplicate of [deploy web application to google app engine on travis-ci - travis is asking for a password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23923424/deploy-web-application-to-google-app-engine-on-travis-ci-travis-is-asking-for)

Comment: You can encrypt sensitive data. See http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encryption-keys/