# deploy web application to google app engine on travis-ci - travis is asking for a password

Tags: google-app-engine, travis-ci

I´m trying to deploy a web application to google app engine after successful build(I´m using maven on my project) and travis-ci is asking for my password. How can I input my password or specify somewhere else?

Comment: Can you link to your build and show the steps that you are currently using to deploy your application? Thanks

Comment: on the travis.yml, I´m doing                                        - wget https://googleappengine.googlecode.com/files/google_appengine_1.8.9.zip -nv
 - unzip -q google_appengine_1.8.9.zip
 - mvn install -DskipTests=false
 - mvn clean package assembly:assembly
 - mvn clean appengine:update <<< password-for-app-engine

Comment: If possible, provide a link to your travis build.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the limited information you are giving us, I am guessing this is happening during the `gcloud preview app deploy` call.

Typically the docker TLS Verification will need a local public key for a Cert and this requires a passcode response. This situation can be avoided by providing the cert using the `travis encrypt-file` api and calling `gcloud auth activate-service-account` during the build. see [gloud cli here](https://github.com/DeepElement/win10-rocks/blob/master/build/gcloud-cli.sh#L16)

Please see the [travis yml here for a full example](https://github.com/DeepElement/win10-rocks/blob/master/.travis.yml)
As always, post questions either here or github for additional walk-through questions.